# Jenkins using a timer to build the newest tag

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins building on every commit and when a new tag is created. Now I need it to build the newest tag every day at 3.
Is there a way to tell the Jenkins cron job to build the newest tag?

I tried adding the cron job to the Jenkins file but it runs on every tag the cron job is in and not just the newest one. Which makes sense but not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Either create a separate Jenkinsfile or parametrize existing one. Such that this new Jenkinsfile would only build :newest tag.

Then create a separate Job which would run only on cron and point to the new Jenkinsfile (or to an existing one with correctly configured parameters).

That's pretty much all you have to do here.